# Excel from XML along with XSD

Tags: xml, parsing, xsd

I am looking for a way to parse an XML document, and store the results in an Excel spreadsheet.

The generated .xls sheet will have rows containing:

- xpath for each element & attributes
- along with information about the element like:

  - data type of the node
  - cardinality and validation (if any)
  - documentation that is specified in an xsd.

This will help me in creating a template that can be used during integration mapping exercises. I am looking for the pointer for what library to use or if there is a utility that is available and does this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specifiy a particular programming language, so, I'll give you what I know works for me in C#...

Try the [NPOI library](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi) for creating Excel files programmatically (this will **not** require that your PC have an MS Office installation)

```
XSSFWorkbook wb1 = null;
using (var file = new FileStream("D:\\banding.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
    wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
}
wb1.GetSheetAt(0).GetRow(0).GetCell(0).SetCellValue("Sample");

using (var file2 = new FileStream("D:\\banding2.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
    wb1.Write(file2);
    file2.Close();
}
```

Then there's tons of documentation on how to use Microsoft's System.Xml namespace for [parsing XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/parsing-xml)

---

UPDATE 
For Java:

---

Similar to my answer above, the [Apache POI library](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) can be used to create an actual Excel file.

Then, googling `xml parsing in Java` and take your pick of options.. e.g.

Import XML-related packages

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import org.jdom2.*;
```

Create a DocumentBuilder

```
 SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
```

Create a Document from a file or stream

```
 File inputFile = new File("input.txt"); 
 SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder(); 
 Document document = saxBuilder.build(inputFile);
```

Extract the root element

```
 Element classElement = document.getRootElement();
```

Examine attributes

```
 //returns specific attribute 
 getAttribute("attributeName");
```

Examine sub-elements

```
 //returns a list of subelements of specified name 
 getChildren("subelementName");  

 //returns a list of all child nodes 
 getChildren();  

 //returns first child node 
 getChild("subelementName");
```

---

Going beyond the above would to turn this into a code writing service which S.O is expressly NOT

Comment: Java is what i am going to use (but that is not very important here). Here this problem is not about creating the Excel document i am ok even if i get CSV. My goal is to iterate through each element and attribute in xml and use Xsd and then print **XPath for the element**, **Cardinality**, **DataType with size**, **documentation**. I have started using soa-model-core to parse xsd. But i was thinking if there is some easiar solution for the same.

Comment: I don't think I am expecting to get the code. I can very well write the code. The point here is not only to get the elements and attribute listed in an XML with their path. Point is to then navigate the XSD also to find details about those elements and attribute. I have found the approach that is to use soa-model-core. But it is a little time taking effort. I was thinking if somebody has done similar work earliar and tools are available to use.

Comment: Ok, well, it sounds like you have the core of what would make a great, more specific S.O. question. If you have a code sample and some kind of explanation about what's making it difficult (if the code sample doesn't already make it obvious) I would probably start a new question focused on that..